# Freeing space from deleted files

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, delete, dd, hidden-files

I had some files deleted that I tried to recover with TestDisk. Because I was in panic, I selected to create an image (.dd file) in the `/home` directory.
The HDD was quickly full, so I terminated the application and I deleted the .dd file.

Then I couldn't boot into Linux. I booted from a live Ubuntu USB disk, and I saw that my HDD had 0 bytes available. That's why I could not boot.

However, the .dd file is not there. I had shift-deleted it.

So how come I cannot see the freed space and I am stuck with 0 bytes left, thus making it impossible to use my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove some files in /var/cache in order to get it running again.
In order to keep more space afterwards you can run:

> sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt clean

in a console.

Comment: @user1584421 Could you please tell me How did remove some files using Ubuntu USB stick? I deleted `rm -f` some files. They were deleted but I see 0 bites left anyway.